# New to web development, want to exercise on HTML5 & CSS

Tags: css, html

i'm a beginner at web development, i've just learned about XHTML 1.0 and CSS and had a brief look at HTML5.

And i don't know. Should i start reading about Javascript now or do exercises in HTML & CSS ... I really think i should exercise, but i don't know how to, or what sites that good for this .

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this question has no objective answer, it doesn't reeaally fit StackOverflow, and will probably be closed :/ Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you start by getting a strong sense of how HTML and CSS work before playing around with JavaScript.

Consider yourself to have a strong sense of those skills when you can do and feel comfortable with the following:

- Create several webpages by hand on
  your own
- Learn a bit about using Divs, and play
  with styling them using classes and
  IDs
- Learn to import your CSS from an external file, and then create an HTML page that can use one of a number of CSS files to code it. Look at [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) to see what I mean
- Learn how to use Firebug in Firefox, and particularly play around with styling padding and margins on content on an existing page using Inspect Element. *2013 update: Chrome's dev tools, are getting much better. [Link](http://docusigndev.github.io/articles/handy-chrome-devtools-tips/)*
  ][2](http://docusigndev.github.io/articles/handy-chrome-devtools-tips/)

For the more interesting JavaScript you are going to want an understanding of the [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM) and you will build that up by doing the above.

**If you are at the point that you feel you have done all of the above, then you are probably ready to dive into JavaScript.**

Do note that HTML5 is also supported somewhat differently between browsers right now, so focus more on HTML for the moment before diving in to HTML5, that way you can avoid having to deal with some odd quirks still present in HTML5, and the fact that HTML5 has somewhat less documentation.

Comment: So, how could i get a "strong sense" of how HTML and CSS work ?

Comment: Ah, good point, let me explain what I mean a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend this book: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/html2/

Its the Build Your Own Web Site The Right Way Using HTML & CSS book, for those who don't want to follow the link.

It is written for newbies and is the book I always recommend for people wanting to learn html and css.

Comment: Whoa, why did this answer get a down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Build your website with HTML/CSS first.  Get comfortable with writing semantic HTML.  Know how to use floats and how to contain them.  After you've made a couple websites with different layouts [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) that with Javascript.

Once you get comfortable with Javascript, take a look at one of the libraries out there to make your job easier ([Jquery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)).